# Averaging Variables to create general equation

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood

My data best fit is the 3 parameter inverse gamma distribution(thereby giving a, b, y variables with each event having a specific value for each variable)  but I am not sure how to create a general equation for these equation...do I average each variable? or is there some other method?

I've seen one researcher use MLE but he doesn't fully explain what he did to create the generalized equation. Is it possible to use MLE to find the mean of an equation with multiple variables and multiple values for each variable?

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a comment in some ways, but it won't fit that easily into the space. Presumably your previous question [Pearson 5/Inverse Gamma/ Double Pareto](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97665/pearson-5-inverse-gamma-double-pareto) provides a context.

My first guess is that

**event** here means subset of your overall dataset

and

**variables** $a, b, y$ mean **parameters** you have fitted ($y$ is a non-conventional choice to denote a parameter, as it so often denotes a response variable). Some notation such as $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ would be more conventional.

My second guess is thus that you have a three-parameter version of the inverse gamma, the third parameter being a location parameter that gives a minimum value.

My third guess is that you want to combine your data into some kind of combined distribution. It is not clear how much sense that makes, and averaging across your different fits would usually be a bad idea, but the usual way forward is to explore various models such as varying $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$; common $\gamma$, varying $\alpha, \beta$ etc. Usually I'd suggest a maximum likelihood formulation. It's hard to provide a concise summary of how to do that and journals in your field don't seem positive about providing the details. Otherwise no-one can comment precisely on a reference you don't give.

Using standard terminology and showing equations would help make your question clearer.

Comment: My data sets are 13 typhoon events, each having its own parameters to an inverse gamma fit. By y i mean gamma, I don't know how to type gamma.

I have used two fits, one is inverse gamma and the other is wakeby all for these 13 data sets and the wakeby gives 5 variables while the inverse gamma gives 3. 

I am trying to create a generalized curve for these data sets since they all are same context.

Comment: *landslides induced by 13 typhoon events.

the wakeby function can be shown as [link](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/auxillar/wakpdf.htm) _italic_ **bold** `code`

[link](http://www.johndcook.com/inverse_gamma.pdf) _italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: To type e.g. $\gamma$, use dollar sign \gamma dollar sign, i.e. LaTeX markup works for such things. The bigger issue is that what want is probably some kind of hierarchical or multilevel model. A multilevel model using Wakeby distributions might be totally original work, but it sounds like a computational nightmare.

Comment: what's a multilevel model?
one friend told me to go in the direction of hyperparameters,

one youtube video person told that I should build the distribution fits then treat each parameter of each distribution as a piece of data then create a new distribution of this data and use MLE to figure out what is the mean of each parameter, then use these means to create the new estimation equation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model